# Subqueries in relationships

Tags: bookshelf.js, knex.js

I have 3 tables: `users`, `subscriptions`, `orders`.

The `subscriptions` table and the `orders` table both have a `user_id` column. I want to define a relationship on the `subscription` bookshelf model that allows me to get the **latest** order.

Right now I have a pretty messy solution. This is my `subscription` model:

```
db.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'subscriptions',

  user() {
    return this.belongsTo('User');
  },

  withLatestOrder() {
    return qb => {
      const orderQuery = db.knex('orders')
        .innerJoin('users', 'users.id', 'orders.user_id')
        .innerJoin('subscriptions', 'users.id', 'subscriptions.user_id')
        .orderBy('orders.created_at', 'DESC')
        .select('orders.id', 'subscriptions.id as subscription_id')
        .as('oq');

      const orderQueryGrouped = db.knex(orderQuery)
        .groupBy('oq.subscription_id', 'oq.id')
        .as('oqg');

      qb
        .leftJoin(orderQueryGrouped, 'oqg.subscription_id', 'subscriptions.id')
        .leftJoin('orders', 'oqg.id', 'orders.id')
        .select('subscriptions.*', 'orders.*');
    };
  }
})
```

This allows me to do something like

```
Subscriptions.forge().withLatestOrder().fetchAll();
```

The problem is, `orders`, even though it is in the results of the SQL statement, is not in the final model. It is quite messy to ready and not immediately obvious to my future self.

Are there any better ways to tackle this problem?

Comment: every time i got such toxic joins in the application code i promote them to a view. if the underlying database provide such feature, don't hesitate. create a migration to make it and them keep you js clean.

Comment: Very good suggestion @sombriks. I'd feel this is actually at the brink of being messy, but since I can't fully work it out a view will do fine.

Comment: hi @rbhalla, are you trying to get the latest order(s) of the current subscription user?

Comment: @absolux, I want to get all users, and with each user, I want the latest order. To provide some clarification, each user has a subscription. And the other is the last thing sent to them based on their subscription.

Comment: @rbhalla have you tried to use `through(User)` like `this.hasOne(Order).through(User).query(qb => qb.orderBy('orders.created_at', 'DESC'))`